# Kogito - REST API to Show SVG of Completed Process Instances?

Tags: kogito

The Process SVG add on seems to only work on persisted process instances.
According to the Kogito documentation, only unfinished process instances are persisted.

Is there a way to create the SVG of the path taken for completed instances?  Preferably without having to persist, as I could have millions of instances.

My use case is to have two rest endpoints - one that just returns the output data object that is the result of the BPMN process, and the other that returns the SVG of the path taken (whether I need to process the BPMN again using the same input or use a previous instance of it, doesn't matter).

I have tried persisting to infinispan and then calling the /svg/processes/{processId}/instances/{processInstanceId} but it never finds the processInstanceId I specify since it completed.

Here are the relevant documentation links:
https://docs.kogito.kie.org/latest/html_single/#con-persistence_kogito-developing-process-services - states that only non-completed process instances are persisted.

https://docs.kogito.kie.org/latest/html_single/#con-bpmn-process-svg-addon_kogito-developing-process-services - since it requires a processInstanceId, that indicates to me that it needs to be persisted, and thus, cannot be a completed instance.

Answer (score 0):

Kogito runtime only keeps the information about active process instances, meaning it gets removed once the process is completed. To keep track of historical information, you need Data Index. The SVG addon will try to query Data Index to retrieve the information about the process instance. From the application side, you need to set the `kogito.dataindex.http.url` property so it can properly communicate and query the service.

Comment: I know this was answered almost a year ago, but maybe you can still clarify if Data Index retains completed processes, not just the ones still active?  I found this in the documentation of Kogito - "The Kogito Data Index Service is not intended for permanent storage or audit log purposes. The Data Index Service is designed to make business domain data accessible for processes that are currently in progress." 

I'm confused whether it does what we need...

Is there a way, via REST API (or other means), to get a list of completed processes in Kogito, in last e.g.3 months ?